# How does mysql read / scan a table while left join occurs?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have two tables, A and B. 
Now if Table A is left joined with B on ac1 = bc2 (ac1 is table A's column and bc1 is table B's column). Does mysql have to read whole table A's ac1 column and put it into memory (RAM) before further condition executed ?

Or can it be read certain amount of rows and after that it will read next certain amounts?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html

Comment: I have already read that. The reason I am asking is what if table A is really really big like gigabytes of data, does msyql still reads whole table A  ? @Strawberry

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly - although it seems to me to belong more appropriately to the dba forum

Answer (score 0):

(the cartesian product) table a left join b, table a all rows multiply table b all rows, table a is base table, if table b no match data, the corresponding columns is null